# GRASS 7 environment setup for Python

Tags: python, grass-gis, grass-7.0, grass.script

I would like to use some GRASS functionality from a Python programme. With GRASS 6 this required the set up of various environment variables, as detailed in the [GRASS Wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python#Linux).

I am trying a similar setup with GRASS 7, as in this example:

```
import os

os.environ['LC_ALL'] = "en_GB.UTF-8"
os.environ['GISBASE'] = "/usr/lib/grass70/"
os.environ['PATH'] = "$PATH:/usr/bin:$GISBASE/bin:$GISBASE/scripts"
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GISBASE/lib"
# for parallel session management, we use process ID (PID) as lock file number:
os.environ['GIS_LOCK'] = "$$"
# path to GRASS settings file
os.environ['GISRC'] = "$HOME/.grass7"
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = "$PYTHONPATH:$GISBASE/etc/python"

import grass.script as grass
env = grass.gisenv()
print env
#List all environment variables
for key, value in os.environ.items(): print key, value 
#Print region extent
r = grass.read_command("g.region", flags='p' )
print r
```

But the end result is an `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grass_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    import grass.script as grass
ImportError: No module named grass.script
```

The basic sanity check shows the script library in the expected folder:

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Mai  3 08:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan  7 08:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai  3 08:44 exceptions
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai  3 08:44 imaging
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  151 Mai  1 21:46 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  363 Mai  3 08:44 __init__.pyc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai  3 08:44 lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai  3 08:44 pydispatch
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Mai  3 08:44 pygrass
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai  3 08:44 script
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mai  3 08:44 temporal
```

What else must be added to this environment setup?

**Update**: I tried [the setup suggested by Gene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/198576/21532), but it produces the same `ImportError` exception:

```
import os

os.environ['GISBASE'] = "/usr/lib/grass70/"
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = "${PYTHONPATH}:$GISBASE/etc/python/"
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GISBASE/lib"
os.environ['GIS_LOCK'] = "$$"
os.environ['GISRC'] = "$HOME/.grass7/rc"

import grass.script as grass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a python script is running, changes to environment variables are no longer effective. They are set up right before runtime and the interpretor will not update them afterwards. `PYTHONPATH` can be updated using the method `sys.path.append()` and that is all.

[A workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25457751/2066215) is to re-execute the script after setting up the environment. This way the interpreter reloads the environment before starting up the script the second time:

```
import os, sys

if 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['GISBASE'] = "/usr/lib/grass70"
    sys.path.append(os.environ['GISBASE'] + "/etc/python/")
    os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = os.environ['GISBASE'] + "/lib"
    os.environ['GIS_LOCK'] = "$$"
    os.environ['GISRC'] = os.environ["HOME"] + "/.grass7/rc"
    try:
        os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)
    except Exception, exc:
        print 'Failed re-exec:', exc
        sys.exit(1)

import grass.script as grass
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this

```
export GISBASE="path_to_your GISBASE"
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:$GISBASE/etc/python/"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GISBASE/lib"
export GIS_LOCK=$$
export GISRC="/path_to/.grass7/rc"
```

Then with Python

```
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE']
gisdb="path_to_your_GISDBASE"
location="Geol"
mapset="test"
gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)
import grass.script as grass
# region extent
d = grass.parse_command('g.region', flags='p')
# d is a Python dictionary
print d
{'ellipsoid:  international': None, 'zone: ': None, 'east:       231750.54768451': None, 'cols:       456': None, 'nsres:      10.0010371': None, 'north:      125744.93437974': None, 'rows:       302': None, 'projection: 99 (Lambert Conformal Conic)': None, 'west:       227192.86784828': None, 'cells:      137712': None, 'ewres:      9.99491192': None, 'datum:      bel72': None, 'south:      122724.62117483': None}
```

But it is easier with the new [PyGRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/libpython/pygrass_index.html)

```
from grass.pygrass.gis.region import Region
reg = Region()
print reg.items
[(u'proj', 99), (u'zone', 0), (u'north', 125744.93437974), (u'south', 122724.62117483), (u'west', 227192.86784828), (u'east', 231750.54768451), (u'top', 284.0), (u'bottom', 156.0), (u'nsres', 10.001037102351026), (u'ewres', 9.994911921557025), (u'tbres', 1.0), (u'rows', 302), (u'cols', 456), (u'cells', 137712)]
print reg.keys()
[u'proj', u'zone', u'north', u'south', u'west', u'east', u'top', u'bottom', u'nsres', u'ewres', u'tbres', u'rows', u'cols', u'cells']
print reg.east
231750.547685
....
print reg.get_bbox()
Bbox(125744.93438, 122724.621175, 231750.547685, 227192.867848)
```

Comment: This setup does not work either, please check the answer for the complete code. Good advice on pyGRASS in any case.

Comment: Another thing: executing this script with Python 3 I get a different exception, the same exception reported in [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/198711/21532).

Comment: the Python version of GRASS GIS is 2.7.x and not 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Now there is also a module under development that simplifies the process. See:

https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Python:_GRASS_GIS_7_with_an_external_library:_grass-session

or

https://github.com/zarch/grass-session