# Exception using PyGRASS: "No module named 'core'"

Tags: python, grass-gis, grass-7.0, pygrass

I am trying PyGRASS on Ubuntu 14.04. I have GRASS 7 installed from the UbuntuGIS PPA:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep grass
ii  grass                                                       7.0.4-1~trusty1                                     all          Geographic Resources Analysis Support System (GRASS GIS)
ii  grass-core                                                  7.0.4-1~trusty1                                     amd64        GRASS GIS core components
ii  grass-dev                                                   7.0.4-1~trusty1                                     amd64        GRASS GIS development files
ii  grass-doc                                                   7.0.4-1~trusty1                                     all          GRASS GIS user documentation
ii  grass-gui                                                   7.0.4-1~trusty1                                     amd64        GRASS GIS graphical user interfaces
ii  libqgisgrass2.0.1                                           2.0.1-2build2                                       amd64        QGIS - shared libraries (libqgisgrass)
ii  libqgisgrass2.8.1                                           1:2.8.1-0+20trusty6                                 amd64        QGIS - shared grass library
ii  libqgisgrass7-2.14.0                                        1:2.14.0+20trusty-ubuntugis                         amd64        QGIS - shared grass library
ii  libqgisgrass7-2.14.1                                        1:2.14.1+20trusty-ubuntugis                         amd64        QGIS - shared grass library
ii  libqgisgrass7-2.14.2                                        1:2.14.2+20trusty-ubuntugis                         amd64        QGIS - shared grass library
ii  libqgisgrass7-2.14.3                                        1:2.14.3+20trusty-ubuntugis                         amd64        QGIS - shared grass library
ii  qgis-plugin-grass                                           1:2.14.3+20trusty-ubuntugis                         amd64        GRASS plugin for QGIS
ii  qgis-plugin-grass-common                                    1:2.14.3+20trusty-ubuntugis                         all          GRASS plugin for QGIS - architecture-independent data
ii  qgis-provider-grass                                         1:2.14.3+20trusty-ubuntugis                         amd64        GRASS provider for QGIS
```

I created a small script inspired on Example 4 of the [Python and GRASS wiki page](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python#pygrass_Library):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Example for pyGRASS usage - vector API

from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import general as g
from grass.pygrass.vector import VectorTopo
from grass.pygrass.modules import Module

vectmap = 'myzipcodes_wake'

g.message("Importing SHAPE file ...")
ogrimport = Module('v.in.ogr')
ogrimport('/home/neteler/gis_data/zipcodes_wake.shp', output=vectmap)

g.message("Assessing vector topology...")
zipcodes = VectorTopo(vectmap)

# Open the map with topology:
zipcodes.open()

# query number of topological features
areas   = zipcodes.number_of("areas")
islands = zipcodes.number_of("islands")
print ('Map: <' + vectmap + '> with %d areas and %d islands' % (areas, islands))

dblink = zipcodes.dblinks[0]
print ('DB name:')
print (dblink.database)
table = dblink.table()
print ('Column names:')
print (table.columns.names())
print ('Column types:')
print (table.columns.types())

zipcodes.close()
```

But its execution fails with an `ImportError` exception:

```
$ python3 pygrass-demo4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pygrass-demo4.py", line 5, in <module>
    from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import general as g
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/pygrass/modules/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from grass.pygrass.modules.interface import Module, ParallelModuleQueue
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/pygrass/modules/interface/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from grass.pygrass.modules.interface import module
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/pygrass/modules/interface/module.py", line 10, in <module>
    from grass.script.core import Popen, PIPE
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/script/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from core   import *
ImportError: No module named 'core'
```

Do I need to install any other library to use PyGRASS? Or is there something else wrong?

**Update I**: [According to Gene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/198744/21532), PyGRASS must be run in a Python 2 environment. However, it only produces a different exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/desouslu/git/pywps-4-demo/processes/pygrass-demo4.py", line 6, in <module>
    from grass.pygrass.vector import VectorTopo
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/pygrass/vector/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import grass.lib.gis as libgis
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/lib/gis.py", line 23, in <module>
    _libs["grass_gis.7.0.4"] = load_library("grass_gis.7.0.4")
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/lib/ctypes_loader.py", line 57, in load_library
    raise ImportError,"%s not found." % libname
ImportError: grass_gis.7.0.4 not found.
```

**Update II**: User Gene suggests a problem with Eclipse itself. However, executing the script from the command line produces the same results:

```
$ python pygrass-demo4.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pygrass-demo4.py", line 6, in <module>
    from grass.pygrass.vector import VectorTopo
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/pygrass/vector/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import grass.lib.gis as libgis
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/lib/gis.py", line 23, in <module>
    _libs["grass_gis.7.0.4"] = load_library("grass_gis.7.0.4")
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/lib/ctypes_loader.py", line 57, in load_library
    raise ImportError,"%s not found." % libname
ImportError: grass_gis.7.0.4 not found.
```

Or alternatively using the Python console:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import general as g
>>> from grass.pygrass.vector import VectorTopo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/pygrass/vector/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import grass.lib.gis as libgis
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/lib/gis.py", line 23, in <module>
    _libs["grass_gis.7.0.4"] = load_library("grass_gis.7.0.4")
  File "/usr/lib/grass70/etc/python/grass/lib/ctypes_loader.py", line 57, in load_library
    raise ImportError,"%s not found." % libname
ImportError: grass_gis.7.0.4 not found.
```

Comment: You run the script in GRASS or from outside ?

Comment: I am running the script from Eclipse.

Comment: Look below in New

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python version of GRASS GIS is 2.7.x and not 3.x

In Python 2.7.11 (Mac OS X)

```
import grass.script.core 
core.__file__
 '/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.pyc
```

In Python 3.5.1

```
 import grass.script.core
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from core   import *
ImportError: No module named 'core'
```

Why ? This is because Python 3 changes the syntax for imports from within a package (look at [Changes in import statement python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173406/835653), for example)

In the init.py (/.../python/grass/script/**init**.py)

```
"""Python interface to launch GRASS GIS modules in scripts
"""
from core   import *
....
```

In Python 3.x this should be

```
from .core import *
```

This syntax  is also valid for Python 2.7.x

#### New

I don't understand your question because:

1. the first thing  you need is to run GRASS GIS from outside and you haven't found the solution in your case (`grass_gis.7.0.4 not found` and [GRASS 7 environment setup for Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198540/grass-7-environment-setup-for-python))
2. the solution that I have given you is for working in the Python shell or in a IPython/Jupyter notebook, not in Ellipse and it works in my case (with GRASS 7.04 or GRASS 7.1 in Mac OS X or LinuxMint)
3. If you want to use Ellipe, there are wikis in the GRASS site ([Eclipse](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Eclipse), [Using Eclipse to develop GRASS Python programs](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Using_Eclipse_to_develop_GRASS_Python_programs)) and answers in GIS SE (as [Difference between python IDLE and eclipse on accessing GRASS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/90162/2581))

Therefore, for me, the main problem is 1). Have you tried the [Python script GRASS GIS 7 with existing location](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Python:_GRASS_GIS_7_with_existing_location) ?

Comment: It does not run with Python 2 either, could you please the check the update to the question? If this other exception is something else then I should accept this answer.

Comment: This exception is not related to Eclipse, please check the update to the question.

Comment: The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable was not being set up correctly. So the main problem was really using the Python 3 interpreter instead of Python 2.