# How to change Python version for GRASS in Windows

Tags: python, grass-gis, windows

I'm using GRASS GIS 7.0.3, the default python version is python2.7. I need python3.5 for my own module. After I edit the 'etc/env.bat' file to change GRASS_PYTHON and PYTHONHOME to the location of my new python .exe file and the new python directory. Then I run GRASS GIS, but I got the following error:

> File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.0.3\etc\grass70.py", line 251
>   os.makedir(tmpdir, 0700) SyntaxError: invalid token

[image]

Am I do it in the right way?

Comment: Please always include errors as text rather than just pictures of errors.  That way they are available to future searches.

Answer (score 3):

From [REQUIREMENTS to compile GRASS GIS 7](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/source/snapshot/REQUIREMENTS.html)

> Python >= 2.6 (for temporal framework, scripts, wxGUI, and ctypes interface)
>   **Note: Python 3 support is still in development**

and

- [[GRASS GIS] #2708: Run GRASS with Python3](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GRASS-GIS-2708-Run-GRASS-with-Python3-td5215769.html)
- [Exception using PyGRASS: “No module named 'core'”](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198711/exception-using-pygrass-no-module-named-core/198744)

Comment: According to the last link, I modify the _init.py_ "import core" to "import .core". I got error "no module named __builtin__". I think the idea is GRASS  haven't support Python3 yet.

Comment: yes ---------------